# Using Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric Answers

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric, fabric-answers

I would like to use Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric Answers together.

According to this [link](https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers/install), in order to setup Fabric Answers, we need to include Fabric API key.

This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) doesn't mention any need for Fabric API key for implementing Firebase Crashlytics.

After some test, I found out that Firebase Crashlytics only works without Fabric API key in AndroidManifest as mentioned in this part of the documentation.

[image: Remove Fabric API Key]

On the other hand, Fabric Answers only works with Fabric API key in AndroidManifest.

Is there anyway we can use both Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric Answers together?

If not, how do I migrate Firebase Crashlytics back to Fabric Crashlytics?

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for asking this did you find a solution to use both Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric answers together.

Comment: I have actually sent Firebase an email about this. Here's their reply: "Thanks for reaching out. Right now it's not possible to use both Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric Answers. I'll let the team know your concerns so we can think about this going forward."

Comment: I think the firebase analytics with custom log events does the same job as Answers doesn't it? How r both different.

Comment: I personally prefer the Fabric console. Their console's summary/home screen provides a list of apps with summarised user analytics data such as new users and active users. Firebase doesn't provide this. Other than that, I enjoy receiving daily email from Fabric detailing daily Answers' user analytics summary (new users, active users, etc) which Firebase doesn't offer either :(

Comment: This whole thing (crashlytics/answers/fabric/firebase – all of it) is so poorly done and documented. wtf.

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way to get setup is to use the Fabric plugin for Android Studio. It will configure your project and put the keys in the correct files/locations.

Crashlytics and Answers both need a fabric key.

Comment: I am referring to Firebase Crashlytics. It is not the same as Fabric Crashlytics.