# Migrate from Firebase Crashlytics to Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

My Android project is currently using Firebase Crashlytics.
I would like to use Fabric Crashlytics.

I have tried following steps from [here](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install), but it is not reporting any crash.

I have also removed this line from app gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:x.y.z"
```

Any solution to this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

In case you want to know the reason behind this migration decision, please refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645669/using-firebase-crashlytics-and-fabric-answers).

Comment: what is the crash?

Comment: Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()

Comment: Thanks. Please follow the steps at fabric.io/kits being sure to add a Fabric.with line, and your API keys to your AndroidManifest.

Comment: Hi @ToddBurner, all these are added (Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
        and Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())). Still nothing displayed in Fabric Crashlytics. Perhaps is it because the app was previously using Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: Fabric crashlytics is owned by google now and google is pushing all to migrate to Firebase crashlytics from fabric crashlytics not the other way around as you are doing

Comment: You probably didn't read the reason behind the migration as stated in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric services will cease to exist [after March 2020](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap).

It would not help to migrate. If you are missing feature parity, you may want to contact Firebase Support.